# RSS and $R^2$ are not suitable for selecting the best model, why?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, residuals, regularization, train

This is in continuation to question [Are RSS and R^2 related to training error only?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221948/are-rss-and-r2-related-to-training-error-only)

In section `6.1.3 Choosing the Optimal Model` of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/index.html), which states following:

> The training error can be a poor estimate of the test error. **Therefore, RSS and $R^2$ are not suitable for selecting the best model.**

The question is: 
we can apply $R^2$ and RSS to test data as well then why these measures are not suitable for selecting the best model?

[image]

Reference: An Introduction to Statistical Learning

Comment: This looks like it's exactly the same question.  Could you elaborate on how you think it differs?

Comment: @whuber I am talking about selecting a model based on RSS and $R^2$ not if these two measures can be applied only to training or test data. If you could answer either this or linked question it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing, because the quotation concerns training vs. testing data rather than using $R^2$ *per se*.  There are threads on this site about the use of $R^2$--perhaps they might answer the question you have.  Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=R+square+model+selection for instance.

Comment: @whuber I have updated this question with proper reference and context, please read the highlighted part.